# Calculus $L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt[n]{x}\sin x\: dx$

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

Calculus: $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt[n]{x}\sin x\: dx$$

My tried:

I think that

We have $$\left|\sqrt[n]{x}\sin x\right|\leq 1$$

Hence

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt[n]{x}\sin x\: dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin x\: dx=2$$

Comment: your answer is correct, but you have to explicit that you applied the dominated convergence theorem to swap integral and limes. Plus it's better for you to split the integral in two parts: from 0 to 1 and from 1 to $\pi$ because the inequality does not hold for all x in the second interval:

So in the end you get:

Comment: The comment above is correct.

Comment: your answer is correct, but you have to explicit that you applied the dominated convergence theorem to swap integral and limes. Plus it's better for you to split the integral in two parts: from 0 to 1 and from 1 to $\pi$ because the inequality does not hold for all x in the second interval. Yet since you integrate continuous functions on a compact inteval it is surely bounded. [sorry for the double comment but I couldn't edit mine anymore] :)

Answer (score 5):

The [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) says that since there is a dominating function $g(x)= \pi$, that is $|x^{1/n} \sin x| \leq g(x)$ on $[0, \pi]$ for $n\geq 1$, and $\int_0^\pi g(x) dx < \infty$, we can pass the limit through:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\pi x^{1/n} \sin x dx = \int_0^\pi (\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{1/n} \sin x) dx = \int_0^\pi \sin x dx = 2.$$

Answer (score 4):

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt[n]{x}\sin x\: dx \leq \sqrt[n]{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin x\: dx=2 \sqrt[n]{\pi} $$

$\forall \delta$, $0\lt \delta \lt \pi$

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt[n]{x}\sin x\: dx\geq   \int_{\delta}^{\pi}\sqrt[n]{x}\sin x\: dx\geq \sqrt[n]{\delta } \int_{\delta }^{\pi}\sin x\: dx=\sqrt[n]{\delta } (1+\cos \delta)$$

so

$$\sqrt[n]{\delta } (1+\cos \delta)\leq \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt[n]{x}\sin x\: dx\leq 2 \sqrt[n]{\pi}$$

Hence,

$$ 1+\cos \delta\leq\varliminf_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt[n]{x}\sin x\: dx\leq \varlimsup_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt[n]{x}\sin x\: dx\leq 2$$

Let $\delta\to 0$, we get

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt[n]{x}\sin x\: dx=2$$